# URL routing in asp.net 4.0 web form not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I am not able to figure it out how to make it work, searched all over internet..
here is my code

```
  void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        //routes.MapPageRoute("Default", "agent/{name}", "~/agent/default.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute("Default", "agent/{name}", "~/agent/default.aspx", false, new RouteValueDictionary { { "name", String.Empty } });
    }
```

My Web.config file

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" >
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>`enter code here`

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">

    </modules>
    <modules>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule"
           type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, 
               System.Web.Routing, 
               Version=4.0.0.0, 
               Culture=neutral, 
               PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I searched alot over internet for asp.net web form routing, done all the step etc but not able to make it work. any help will be very thankful .

Comment: show us the logs... what urls have you tried is the server even seeing them?

Comment: i am trying http://localhost:40933/agnet/username Where i can see log in localhost?

Comment: This depends on how you set up IIs.  The event log is located in right click computer icon select manage.  Then go to event viewer.

Comment: i am not able to see logs, there alot of log file in event viewer...

Comment: `agnet` will not work since your routes all use `agent`.  You have the n and the e reversed.  You should get a 401 and see the wrong URLs in the IIs logs.

Comment: sorry but its just a spelling mistake in typing i renamed it to http://localhost:40933/profile/name

Comment: @hogan can you check the code above if it is correct?

Comment: I can't check the code and tell you if it is right if you don't post what your code is.  You just said you changed the code.  This code can't be what you are doing, how can I check it.  YOU should check your IIs logs.  If you don't know how to find those logs google it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't copy following file on server:

**PrecompiledApp.config**

after adding it, & restarting IIS worked form.